# Cant Save Post Request Body Data

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I am having trouble saving the data from a fetch post request using Node.js and React.js. I am calling the fetch request from a function inside a React component class. I want to query some userid from my database then save it to one of the React component instance variables ie "this.userid" however, whenever I assign the value to one of the empty variables I check it outside of the ".then" statements you can see it was never assigned.

Does anyone know of a run around or the proper way to perform the fetch request? I am creating a simple login post request and want to save the userid once its returned from the API.

```
class LandingPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.data = data
}   
login(e){
    var that = this;
    function log(id){
       that.userid = id
    }
    fetch("/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.data)
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(json =>log(json.userid))
   /both show undefined
   console.log(that.userid, this.userid)  
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the data outside of the then scope. It doesn't exist there, so you will have to call setState with the retrieved data inside the .then().

change
`.then(json =>log(json.userid))`
to

```
.then(json => {
  that.setState({userid: json.userid})
})
```

then, after the component updated, the state with userid is available

Update: alternatively, you can use async await and build it like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    userId: null
  }

  useFetch = async e => {
    const raw = await fetch("/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.data)
    });

    const json = await raw.json();

    this.setState({
      userId:json
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.userId === null)
      this.useFetch();
    return (
      <div>Loading some data</div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

tested and working component.

Comment: i changed my then statement to that.setState but it didnt define it either :/

Comment: Are you sure you used the `var that = this;` and `that.setState()`?

Comment: @JLask check the update, i wrote an async await version for you